# Why doesn't console.log() concatenate strings?

Tags: javascript, console.log

In this example I try to print one asterisk on the first line, two on the second and so on:

```
var n = 5;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    console.log('*');
  }
  console.log('\r\n');
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But in the Chrome console I see this:

```
*
2 *
3 *
4 *
5 *
```

Why is this?

Comment: If you print the same string multiple times, instead of printing it on a new line the developer console will put a number in front of the string, indicating how many times that string has been printed the same.

Comment: Because Chrome console is interactive, it's not a plain stdout character stream to which you can print strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing that because it's how dev tools handles multiple occurrences of the same value for the purposes of clarity.

You can use an array to achieve the effect you're after. Also note that we change `j<i` to `j<=` so that it outputs on the 5th.

Then, we use the `.join('')` method to flatten the array into a string.

Also, since we are console.logging on every **iteration** loop, a new line will be added automatically as it's one log *per* loop.

```js
var n = 5;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var arr = [];
  for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

    arr.push('*');

  }
  console.log(arr.join(''));
}
```

Please note that you wouldn't need an array if you were printing this into the DOM - it would work as you originally intended it to do.

**Update:** Ivar made a great solution as well and that's to use the [`String.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function which only requires you to use one loop.

```js
var n = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var str = '*';
  str = str.repeat(i);
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: In this case you could also use the [`String.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). In that case you only need one loop.

Comment: @Ivar Great addition - I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` is not designed to precisely control the rendering of the output. It is a log writer, not a terminal layout API.

It puts each log message on a line of its own, and collapses duplicate, sequential log messages into a single message with a count of the number of times it occurred next to it.

Comment: Thanks, there is one more problem, is there any Edit text in this forum for changing some text in my example?

Comment: @ASiDesigner — If you have a new question then you should ask a new question and not edit an old one.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the way it works, basically. Each call to `console.log` outputs a new log entry. Each log entry is in its own line.

If you log the same string multiple times, they will get summarized into one entry with the count in front.

Don't mistake `console.log` with `Console.Write` in C# or similar. It's more like `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: So how to overcome this? should I do it in a string object and dump the string to the console?

Comment: @ASiDesigner Exactly